why doesn't the loop break (floating point number precision)
I have been trying everything to get this to work. So basically I want the program to stop after the change of digits is less than 14 digits after the point. But apparently that case never occurs.
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    double stand_n = 1.0;

    for (double stand = 1.0; stand_n - stand <= 10e-15; stand = stand_n)
    {
        stand_n = 1.0 / stand + stand / 2.0;
        printf("%.14lf\n", stand_n);
    }
}

Output:
1.50000000000000
1.41666666666667
1.41421568627451
1.41421356237469
1.41421356237309
1.41421356237309
1.41421356237309
1.41421356237309
1.41421356237309
...


Have you tried printing stand_n - stand in the loop?

Side note: you're pushing very close to the precision limits of IEE754 binary64 format, which is very likely to be the representation of your double.  You get about 15-16 significant decimal digits to work with, and you're looking at differences in the 15th.

Instead of guessing the number of decimal digits to print, use DBL_DECIMAL_DIG as in printf("%.*g\n",  DBL_DECIMAL_DIG , stand_n) or use "%a" printf("%a\n", stand_n).  This provides better insight into what is happening without being verbose.

@John Bollinger, It's so close that replacing <= 1e-14 with == 0  in my answer doesn't affect the result. So it's only because of luck that the loop ends with a tolerance that small. Another series might oscillate around the limit with a difference larger than this tolerance and thus loop forever.

@ikegami
Indeed.  I tried to demonstrate the superiority of a relative
comparison here, but basically couldn't.  The absolute comparison against
10e-15 shouldn't work, yet it does, and pretty well.  I suppose
this is because quadratic convergence is so darn good & fast that
it hardly matters if your termination condition is way off.

You perform stand = stand_n right before performing stand_n - stand <= 10e-15, so stand_n - stand is always zero, so the loop never ends.
Three errors.

The incorrect timing of the check mentioned above.
You want repeat while the difference is >= 10e-15, not while the difference is <= 10e-15.
You want to compare the absolute value of the difference.

Also, 10e-15 normalizes to 1e-14.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main( void )
{
    double stand = 1.0; 
    while ( 1 ) {
        double stand_o = stand;

        stand = 1.0 / stand_o + stand_o / 2.0;
        printf( "%.14lf\n", stand );

        if ( fabs( stand_o - stand ) <= 1e-14 )
            break;
    }
}

1.50000000000000
1.41666666666667
1.41421568627451
1.41421356237469
1.41421356237309
1.41421356237309

